# Excel Auto Format Time Like Google when inputting

Tags: excel, google-sheets, time

I created a timesheet on google and format a cell with time (Format -> Number -> Time). When I type in '1am' + tab it automatically is formatted to h:mm:ss AM/PM or 1:00:00 AM.

12am -> 12:00:00 AM,
12pm -> 12:00:00 PM

I downloaded the file to excel locally and the auto format when typing in NumberAM or NumberPM and tab doesn't work. I have to manually type out the entire time, 12:00:00 PM. Does anyone know how to fix this for excel.

```html
<iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/MtHffAWelJ7rM9TOip" width="480" height="240" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/MtHffAWelJ7rM9TOip">via GIPHY</a></p>
```

https://giphy.com/gifs/MtHffAWelJ7rM9TOip

```html
<iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/htOQWq5wqJs8B0bHlW" width="480" height="240" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/htOQWq5wqJs8B0bHlW">via GIPHY</a></p>
```

https://giphy.com/gifs/htOQWq5wqJs8B0bHlW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel, after you set your desired cell format, you need to use a space before am/pm.  eg

```
1 a
1 am
1 p
```

all work ok here.

AAMOF, you don't need to format the cell beforehand, unless you need something other than the default time format.

Without the space, the input is interpreted as a text string.

Comment: Oh man... Sometimes the simple things. Thanks!